# Why the character of any representation is a central function?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Why the character of any representation is a central function?

[image]

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Because similar matrices have the same trace. Or are you also looking for an explanation of that (which is a pure linear-algebra fract)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the character $\chi(g)$ is the trace of the action of $g$ and because any two similar matrices have the same trace.